# Error on Taylor formula argument

Tags: calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Question:

[image]

My solution:

$$f''(x) = \frac{f(x+h) - 2f(x) + f(x-h)}{h^2} $$

$$f''(x) = \frac{1}h \frac{f(x+h) - 2f(x) + f(x-h)}h$$

$$f''(x) =  \frac{1}{h} [f'(x)-f'(x) = 0]$$

So because the second derivative cannot be $0$ for all $x$ the argument is wrong.

**Basically I am wondering if anyone can confirm if my argument makes sense or not**

Comment: You haven't identified the error in the given argument, which is: $\xi$ need not be the same in two formulas on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the comment by NormalHuman, I would point out that your argument is wrong. In fact, we do not have
$$f'(x) = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h},$$
which was used in your proof.

As a counterexample, consider $f(x) = x^2$. Then,
$$f''(x) = \frac{f(x+h) - 2 \, f(x) + f(x - h)}{h^2}$$
holds for all $x,h \in \mathbb{R}$, but $f''(x) \ne 0$.